# How to compile a c# dotnet 5 isolated function app on notebook with ARM64

Tags: c#, .net, azure, macos, arm64

I have got a MacBook with Arm64 cpu and i need to compile an Azure function app written in c# with dotnet 5 on it. I also have parallels with Windows 11 ARM64 running on it.
The azure function app references these packages and they need dotnetcore3.1 to be available.

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage" Version="4.0.4" />
```

Even a newly create, empty function app needs those references, otherwise i cannot compile the blueprint, that is being created by `func new` with dotnet-isolated.

Does anybody have any idea, how I can either install dotnetcore3.1 for Mac OS ARM64 or dotnetcore3.1 for Windows ARM64 or replace the Extensions with a package, that does not need dotnetcore3.1??

Btw: It is working properly on the x64 MacBook, where I simply installed dotnet5 and dotnetcore3.1 with brew and then `dotnet build`succeeded.

I know this is not 100% a programming question, but I believe stackoverflow is nevertheless the best place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a "real" solution to the problem, but I was able to convince my colleagues to upgrade to function app version 4 with dotnet 6.
Using dotnet 6 the function app does no longer have the dependency for dotnetcore3.1 to build the solution, so the dotnet 6 build with Windows ARM64 or Mac OS ARM64 is pretty straight forward.

Thank you to everybody who tried to help!

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody have any idea, how I can either install dotnetcore3.1 for Mac OS ARM64 or dotnetcore3.1 for Windows ARM64 or replace the Extensions with a package, that does not need dotnetcore3.1??

On an ***Arm-based Windows PC***, all Arm64 versions of .NET are installed to the normal *`C:\Program Files\dotnet\`* folder. However, when you install the **x64** version of .NET 6 SDK, it's installed to the *`C:\Program Files\dotnet\x64\`* folder.

**macOS** has standalone installers that can be used to install the .NET 6 SDK:

- [x64 and Arm64 CPUs](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0)

On an ***Arm-based Mac***, all Arm64 versions of .NET are installed to the normal `_/usr/local/share/dotnet/_` folder. However, when you install the **x64** version of .NET 6 SDK, it's installed to the *`/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet/`* folder.

Please Refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net60#arm-based-windows-pcs) for ARM-based Windows PC and this [MSFT documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/macos#arm-based-macs) for ARM-based macOS PC.

Comment: That is a really nice overview, but i cannot neither find an installer for dotnetcore3.1 for windows arm 64 nor for mac os arm 64.